# R qbeta with vectors slow speed

Tags: r, performance, beta-distribution

I have 3 vectors called `vp`, `va` and `vb`:

`vp` contains 1.5 million random probabilities

`va` contains 1.5 million alpha values

`vb` contains 1.5 million beta values

I am trying to create an output that is a vector that looks like:

```
vanswer <- c(qbeta(vp,va,vb))
```

I know that this works, however the speed is tremndously slow with such large amounts of data and I am trying to find a way to speed it up. I have also tried doing the computation in a matrix with `cbind()` as well as using `sapply()`, but I cannot find the right way.

Any help would be helpful!

Comment: are all the values unique?

Comment: ... otherwise I think you're going to have a very hard time getting this any faster, as vectorized `qbeta` is all executed in C code.

Comment: Not every Alpha and Beta are unique. All the probabilities are unique. What is C code? and what else could I do to make this faster?

Comment: someone in the R chat room suggested that you could parallelize this (i.e. run it on multiple cores, or multiple workstations: see `?clusterMap` in the `parallel` package that comes with R.